# How can I achieve a 25V - 5V @10A buck circuit, and a 25V - 8V @6.5A buck circuit?

Tags: dc, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck

I'm a computer engineer major in my senior year.
My team and I are making a SmartKart, and I'm responsible for power management and power designing.

Right now, based on several components we will be using, we're looking at doing two step-down DC-DC converters, one being 24V to 5V @ 10A, the other being 24V to 8V @ 6.5A. (This is assuming worse case)

The problem that I'm stuck at is how can I make these power circuits using the switch-mode method, and buck topology, or another simple topology? What IC chip would you recommend? It doesn't have to be isolated.

Things that I have tried to gain a better understanding, or achieve this goal would be the following:

1. Reading the Art Of Electronics, especially the sections that talk about switch-mode power supplies.
2. Using the famous LM2576 -5.0 chip to gain an understanding of the functionality of this technology, and made a prototype board on it.
3. Using the LTC3890 to develop two-buck outputs, which worked in simulation, but failed in practice.
4. Using the LT1074HV, and utilized a transformer (Tapped inductor) to achieve higher current, which worked in simulation, but not in practice.
5. Using the LT1270A, and utilized the SEPIC topology, which worked in practice and simulation, although it blew up on me twice when current got above ~7A, which proved to be unstable.
6. Using Webench Power Designer to look at some references, although many of those designs require components that are either out of stock and impractical to breadboard some of those designs, or difficult to simulate using LTspice. I also would want to minimize surface-mount components if possible.

I'm very frustrated and like to have some guidance on this, any help is appreciated.
I like to minimize the circuit, and use as few components as possible, and breadboard it, but if I need to use surface-mount components I do have those breadboard adapters for them.

Thank you

Comment: `use as few components as possible` ... do you mean discrete component? ... would a module count as one component?

Comment: What will the DC/DC converters be powering?

Comment: You could try reverse engineering an existing module, such as this one from Aliexpress   tinyurl.com/yckkuan5   Input Voltage: 6V to 40V DC(10V to 40V is suggested)  
Output Voltage: 1.2V to 36V DC  
Output Current: 20A(max.), 15A(suggested)  5.60 GBP

Comment: To create your own includes make PCB, buy elements, assemble it. Consider the cost and time. You can just buy ready for use module, with adjustable output. You may even alternate it, replace trimpot with two resistors.

Comment: - I would like to build my own if possible. 

- They will be powering a variety of things such as a servo motor, microcontrollers, LCD screens, development boards, cameras, etc. 

- That's a good suggestion on reverse engineering an existing module.

Comment: Use exisitng help tools such as TI's Webench: https://www.ti.com/design-resources/design-tools-simulation/webench-power-designer.html

Comment: For 5:1 ratio I would prefer some transformer topology like forward converter. It helps you decrease voltage using transformer ratio rather then duty. 50W isn't a big deal, it just must work. Using datasheet examples you can't make a mistake. If isolation isn't needed you can avoid the optocoupler part to reduce a BOM.

Comment: You can have a look at my [page](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm) and download my [APEC 2019](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf) seminar dedicated to the buck converter.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so you summed all your 5V loads and get 10A, so you decided on a 5V 10A converter... But then, you have to distribute +5V everywhere, at pretty high current, which needs fat wires. And you have 8V also, which means three power distribution networks all over the vehicle.

I'm going to suggest another option: distribute 24V only, and use point-of-load conversion to 5V or 8V. This will make the wiring much simpler, and if one of the loads misbehaves or shorts, its local converter should limit current but that won't bring down the entire 5V bus.

One solution or the other could be preferable, depending on where your 5V loads are located in the vehicle.

For example, these [5V 1A canned converters](https://fr.farnell.com/recom-power/r-78e5-0-1-0/convertisseur-dc-dc-5v-1-a-trav/dp/2760747) are pretty cheap, and there are a lot of similar products available from many manufacturers.

If you want a solution right now, use canned DC-DC modules like the one linked above. If you want to learn to design your own DC-DC, then of course, you should design your own. It will probably be more expensive and take a lot longer, but you'll get experience.

Under no circumstances should you use the counterfeit "LM2596" from aliexpress with the garbage quality capacitors that will die quickly.

Since this will be your first DC-DC, I'd recommend starting with something simple with less traps and pitfalls, especially regarding layout. Therefore, a synchronous buck chip with integrated MOSFETs gives you a lot less opportunities to make mistakes than a controller with external MOSFETs. Likewise, high current like 10A is more difficult than just a few amps.

So if you decide to roll your own, a bunch of boards with say, 2-3 amps output current each will be a lot easier than a big one with 10A current.

If your "24V" comes from a battery and is not really 24V, make sure you select a chip that will work over the whole voltage range of the battery, with a bit of margin. If you use regenerative braking, make sure that won't boost your 24V bus to some unhealthy high voltage.

> Using Webench Power Designer to look at some references, although many of those designs require components that are either out of stock and impractical to breadboard some of those designs

Forget about breadboarding, none of these chips will perform properly (or work at all) without a proper layout and PCB, except maybe something old, low frequency and inefficient like LM2596. You could prototype it deadbug on a ground plane, but honestly that's not necessary. If you don't mess the layout and parts selection, it'll work. If this is your first time, you should definitely ask a question with your layout and get some reviews before sending it to the PCB fab. You should do a search for all the others who posted questions about their DC-DCs that didn't work, read the answers, and understand why it didn't work.

Likewise it will have to be all-SMDs, because thru-hole components have too much inductance for the frequencies these things run at. This is especially important for capacitors. SMD adapters for breadboards also won't work.

Don't worry about it though, once you get the hang of it, it's not difficult. If you're scared of SMDs, order a bunch of the cheapest chips you can find with the same package and get some soldering experience. Or just get a bunch of dead boards from the trash, remove some components with the hot air station then solder them back on.

[Here is a URL for a DigiKey search](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?s=N4IgjCBcoBwOxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIAzAJwBsNArCALqEAOALlCAMrsBOASwB2AcxABfQmDAAGRCBSQMOAsTIgALDJgUacwlp3aQB7RRhUTms1X3WdVCKYcVmbTpB79hYyeABMltAKaFh4hCSQ5P4acHAyNFZgNHD0VBpJgTApSRRg9Hm5GmkwVv4y%2BelJcHpwGVJwMP4MZf5wYFT%2BZTL0MAVuIBxcvIKiEoT0cK7BisrhalHgDNldUjDFVKVrNBqySTAHHUm29HtSnRWM5xrr9eBUU-HH8LTdMv5gqyAfBT1lYDAEghCB9Op9Wv4KIUQZDisDvs1PhkWIMPF5Rr4pBRyvJZmFVJFyBpIdjLIRsf5-H0BkNPCMfOMQABaLozKD8ACuBPUjCYfiZQWQ7L4XIi6ggfMITMYbKU%2BLFiy%2BiRB9DsYHhrj5fkSwQEABMuEzZE5UVwrOwAJ6sXBcdDYFDicRAA). Given current circumstances, you'll probably have to get what's available, buy some extra, and live with that. So let's go with something cheap so you can buy more than enough to burn a few chips. I sorted by price.

Personally, I'd go with [this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/rohm-semiconductor/BD9E302EFJ-E2/6131354) for up to 2A output current, mostly because it's in stock, and the package is not difficult to handle, it's a SO-8 with a thermal pad. It's a simple chip, with not a lot that can go wrong. It has overcurrent and short circuit protection. There are other similar chips, with low pin count. I've never used a Rohm buck chip so I can't comment on the quality, but well, TI's and AD's are mostly out of stock, so...

A higher efficiency option would be [this one from AO](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ2151PQI-05.pdf), if you feel adventurous enough to deal with the package. There are three different ones that look similar, so there's probably one that suits your application better than the others. They're all "non-stock", but then again, these days, all components are "non-stock" so who cares.

If you absolutely want to do 10 Amps, then I can give a five star review to LTC3851, having tried it. It is much more complicated, since it uses external MOSFETs and a lot more parts, and the inductor choice will be a problem.

Anyway. If you want to breadboard modern chips that run at high frequency, it will have to look like that thing I built a while ago, it's copper tape, kapton tape, and ground plane, that gives a really low inductance:

[image]

If you want to breadboard it the old fashioned way, then maybe LM2596 but it's already 150kHz, and you'll need to do it over a ground plane anyway.

-- Bonus

> I believe I will use the power designer tool and keep it default. Make no changes and get all the components that were in the bill of materials (If I can find them).

You can substitute, but from what I remember of the questions with failed DC-DC's...

- Caps:

The buck draws a square wave current, so ripple current on the input cap is close to the full output current. SMD MLCCs have very low ESR, a few mOhms for 10µF, it's roughly inverse proportional to capacitance. They're tiny and cheap, but they will handle several amps of ripple current each! They also have very low inductance due to size. If you use electrolytic caps, then you have to carefully consider the ESR and ripple current rating. Using a general purpose aluminium cap (100µF, 0.5-1 ohm ESR, 200mA ripple current) won't work.

You can get specs for murata caps on their [website](https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/index.html?lcid=en-us), click on "detailed" tab and "C-DC bias" to get the actual value of your capacitor at the voltage it gets. You should use X7R/X5R dielectric, at least 35V rated for the input. Manufacturer doesn't matter as long as you buy it from a place that can be trusted to not sell you Z5U instead of X7R (ie, not banggood). Just sort by price. Smaller size (not value) caps lose more capacitance with voltage, so sometimes a larger lower value has more µF at 24V than a smaller higher value cap. Also they're expensive in small quantity, but cheap in bulk, so sometimes more caps in parallel end up cheaper than a higher value cap. So if you need 22µF, consider 2x 10µF, you get half the ESL, lower capacitance loss with voltage, and it'll be cheaper if you go over the quantity discount like 25 or 50.

- Inductor

A good criteria is to pick a shielded SMD inductor with a saturation current similar or greater than the current limit rating of the switch in your DC-DC chip. It's somewhere in the datasheet under "maximum switch current" or something. This way, if the output is shorted, the chip's current limit will trigger before the inductor saturates too much. If the inductor saturates at a low current, it loses its inductance, so current runs away very fast, and the chip has to turn off the MOSFET while that happens, so it can overheat. No need to overdo it and waste money though. Besides that, search for Bourns SRR1280, that's the look of a shielded power inductor, get something that looks similar. Core material depends on frequency, for the usual buck chips at a few hundred kHz, ferrite core.

Heavy components like inductors or connectors can break off the board in case of shock. If you hand solder, a few vias in the pad let the solder grab more on the board.

The price of high current inductors should convince you to use lower current point-of-load DC-DCs...

- Connectors

Make sure you think about the connectors! Maybe USB for the 5V output, maybe something cheap, robust and available like Molex PC motherboard or barrel connectors for the input... your choice, but wires soldered to a board in a vibrating environment tend to break off, and connectors are more convenient and robust.

Minimum EMI headaches occur when the input and output grounds are next to each other.

- Screw holes

Don't forget the screw holes, and make sure there will be no shorts to the screws, leave enough clearance, not the default 0.2mm, make the holes big enough... If you want to mezzanine it over your other boards, it has to align...

- Footprints are free

Leave some exposed pads to add more input/output caps, just in case. No harm done either in enlarging the inductor pads a bit so you can fit a bigger one just in case. Also a LED on the output is nice, just run it at 1mA.

Comment: Given that this is a project, I can't sufficiently vote up @bobflux 's comment to route the 24V and use "canned" converters.  You've likely got more than enough fish to fry, and you don't want to have to wonder why your power system isn't working.  I would look at something like these from Digikey for about $10: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/traco-power/TSR-2-2450/9383726

Comment: @AndrewLentvorski yeah there are [so many to choose from](https://tinyurl.com/2p8ppbm4)

Comment: I just saw this since finals have been a bit challenging, but I wanted to say thank you. 

I really appreciate the feedback you gave me, based on your advice and other people's advice. I believe I will use the power designer tool and keep it default. Make no changes and get all the components that were in the bill of materials (If I can find them). I will also use the default PCB board layout and print it as it is to eliminate any errors I might do.

If this doesn't work, although it should. I will go with the other alternative: point-of-load conversion. 

Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome! I've added some more stuff in the answer.